# Why Ionic slide show is not working?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a simple funky problem with ionic slide show, I am using the exact same method that ionic website says ([Ionic Slide Show](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/)).

The code that I have is like the following:

```
<ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)" ng-repeat="img in itemPictures">
    <ion-slide>
       <img style="padding: 5px; border: solid 1px #EFEFEF;" class="full-image" ng-src="mydomain/{{img.Image_Path}}/{{img.Image_SRC}}"/>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

itemPictures array has the correct data, The problem is I am getting the images underneath each others where each image is like a slider by itself.

Thanks guys!!

Comment: Do let me know if my answer helped.

Answer (score 1):

`<ion-slide-box>` is parent element of slider. It contains `<ion-slide>` elements inside it. You are repeating `<ion-slide-box>` instead you need to put `ng-repeat` in `<ion-slide>`.

```
   <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">
        <ion-slide ng-repeat="img in itemPictures">
           <img style="padding: 5px; border: solid 1px #EFEFEF;" class="full-image" ng-src="mydomain/{{img.Image_Path}}/{{img.Image_SRC}}"/>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
```

Please look again at usage in documentation, you will understand.

Comment: Hi @mudasser, Thanks for your answer. Actually, I knew that I had to move ng-repeat to the ion-slide element. However, I am now getting none of the images.

Comment: Well this is of course because of wrong image path, you should  check what image path you are getting in `ng-src` .

Comment: I tried to inspect the element (ion-slide) .. the number of the slides is correct, the src of the images is correct.. however, I found that for each image there is src and ng-src attribute .. I did not understand why

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, because ng-src ultimately creates `src` attribute by processing path. Did you check path by copying from there and open in seperate tab ?

Comment: Can you putt basic working demo of your code here: play.ionic.io  , so i can see what is wrong.

Comment: Oh, I see what's the problem.. class="full-image" once I delete this class the image will appear .. any idea why and how to maintain the full-image class?

Comment: i don't know what are you doing in `full-image`, if you want image to fit whole slider, you need to do this `.full-image {max-width:100% !important;
max-height:100% !important; }`

Comment: full-image is a pre-defined css class

Comment: then define your custom class with another name, by the way built in full-image has this syle  `.full-image {
  width: 100%;
}`

Comment: I tried your css code.. I figured out that if you try to determine the width percentage it will make the images disappear

Comment: Basically, I am trying to do something like that http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#card-showcase where the image is a slide show of many images

Comment: full-image class is not a problem, look at this http://play.ionic.io/app/c93a7be16e65